# Css style on hover not being applied

Tags: html, css

Below code is attempting to style a href element. Initially its green but on hover should change to yellow :

```
<a class="myclass" href="http://www.google.com">G</a>

.myclassA:link, :visited, :active, :active { 
   color: green;
}, A:hover, :focus { 
   color: yellow;
}
```

Problem is the href is not changing color on hover. Is my styling syntax incorrect ?

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/uzaG9/87/

Comment: Where's the element with the class `mycss`? And why is there a comma separating the rules? Seems like all your issues are typos.

Comment: You are adding the css for the class `mycss` you should do `myclass`in your example

Comment: @j08691 typos fixed, thanks

Comment: Danm !!! seriously !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are syntax errors in your CSS. Check this updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/alexcoady/uzaG9/855/

```
a:link, a:visited, a:active { 
    color: green;
}

a:hover, a:focus { 
    color: yellow;
}
```

Or if you wanted to target the class directly:

```
.myclass:link, .myclass:visited, .myclass:active { 
     color: green;
}

.myclass:hover, .myclass:focus { 
    color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: The key problem, you might want to add, is that they added a comma in between the two selectors.

Comment: But I think the OP wanted `a.myclass:link, a.myclass:visited`, etc as selectors

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some errors in your CSS including some typos

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
.myclass:link,
.myclass:visited,
.myclass:active {
  color: green;
}
.myclass:hover,
.myclass:focus {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
 <a class="myclass" href="http://www.google.com">Google Me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css rule does not match your links. Selectors separated by spaces are descendant selectors.

```
.mycss a --> matches any <a> element within an element with classname mycss
a.myclass --> matches <a> elements with classname mycss
```

**An example:**

```css
.wrapper a {
  color: red;
}

a.link {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#">Wrapped link</a>
</div>
<a class="link">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the changes..

```
.myclass:link, .myclass:visited, .myclass:active { 
 color: green;
}

.myclass:hover, .myclass:focus { 
color: yellow;
}
```